# How to send ENTER key stroke using protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to "sendkeys" and press "enter".

Tried something like ,

`browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform().`

Here is my code :

```
  let e1 = this.editName;
  await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', 
    e1);
    await e1.click();
    await browser.sleep(500);
    await this.editNameUnderFocus.clear();
    await this.editNameUnderFocus.sendKeys('uitest123');
    await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```

The above code doesn't throw any errors but the changes are not saved.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: The syntax you use to press enter appears to be correct, when you watch your test, is it properly doing `sendKeys` to the element?

Comment: await this.editNameUnderFocus.sendKeys('uitest123', protractor.Key.ENTER);

Comment: It could be that the key is sent to the document instead of the active element. Try `await this.editNameUnderFocus.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);`

Comment: Well ,  i tried both , seems doesn't work .. i do no see the changes being saved!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.txtAdditional.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

Try sending the tab key on the web element

`txtAdditional` is the element

Answer (score 0):

Add '\n' at the end of the string to send ENTER

EX:  `this.editNameUnderFocus.sendKeys('uitest123\n');`